# How to propagate exit code from nested bash commands

Tags: bash, shell

In the following scenario

```
$ echo $(cat some-file-that-doesnt-exist)
```

I'd like to have the outer command fail (exit code != 0) if the inner command fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need stopping the command chain on error (instead of propagating their exit code) you can use logical AND operator `&&`:

```
x=$(cat some-file-that-doesnt-exist) && echo "$x"
```

Combine with logical or `||` you can do:

```
x=$(cat input.a) || x=$(cat input.b) || x=$(cat input.c) && echo "input is: $x"
```

Where `echo` only run when one or more file exists.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way (and at the moment the only way I can think of, although it wouldn't surprise me if bash has some option setting that short-circuits the standard process and does what you want, but I would be loathe to use such a thing if it does exist) is to break up the command into pieces.  That is:

```
$ content=$(cat /p/a/t/h) && echo "$content"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case of `cat` as the inside command, you can use the `$(<filename` structure. This will effectively eliminate the internal command, and will cause error processing (set -e, ERR trap, ...) to get triggered if the file does not exists

```
x=$(</path/to/file)
```

Comment: `echo $(<missing-file) ; echo $?` yields `0`. I need it to yield anything different than 0. If I need to have the extraction into variable, then essentially this is the same answer as the others.